# How to add keyboard input languge?

Tags: keyboard, language-support, preferences

I have tried to look up how to input a new keyboard language, but all the answers I find say to start by clicking on 'Dash'. I  am very confused about 'Dash'. It doesn't seem to exist on my version of Ubuntu. When I press the 'Windows' key, all it does is switch between applications.
I am trying to add a keyboard input language so I can type in English and Spanish, but I can't even find 'Preferences'. This is what my desktop looks like: https://prnt.sc/10rlatl Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: Press "Activities" and type "keyboard layout".

Answer (score 0):

The dash more often called the dock is the bar on the left side click the box on the bottom to access the rest of the items and find settings. From there find the language settings.